# R Dataframe new column with rolling correlation of two other columns

Tags: r, correlation

I've been stuck for about one hour with something probably simple.
I have a dataframe and I would need to add a new column containing the correlation of two other columns.
It's important to note I would need the output to be a new dataframe column containing all initial rows, including those with no correlation.
Here is my code:

```
data <- mtcars[1:50,]
data$out <- rollapply(data.frame(data$mpg, data$wt), 8 ,function(x) cor(x[,1],x[,2]), by.column=FALSE, fill=NA)
```

if you check the output, for some weird reason the tail has a lot of NA rows:

```
> tail(data)
      mpg cyl disp hp drat wt qsec vs am gear carb new_col out
NA.12  NA  NA   NA NA   NA NA   NA NA NA   NA   NA    <NA>  NA
NA.13  NA  NA   NA NA   NA NA   NA NA NA   NA   NA    <NA>  NA
NA.14  NA  NA   NA NA   NA NA   NA NA NA   NA   NA    <NA>  NA
NA.15  NA  NA   NA NA   NA NA   NA NA NA   NA   NA    <NA>  NA
NA.16  NA  NA   NA NA   NA NA   NA NA NA   NA   NA    <NA>  NA
NA.17  NA  NA   NA NA   NA NA   NA NA NA   NA   NA    <NA>  NA
```

why is this happening?
Also, if I check the head, only the first 3 rows show NA in the "out" column but I would expect to have an NA value in the first seven rows of the "out" column.

```
> head(data,10)
                   mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb      new_col        out
Mazda RX4         21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4  6  --  2.62         NA
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4 6  --  2.875         NA
Datsun 710        22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1  4  --  2.32         NA
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1 6  --  3.215 -0.6294594
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2  8  --  3.44 -0.6231828
Valiant           18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1  6  --  3.46 -0.6374638
Duster 360        14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4  8  --  3.57 -0.9454915
Merc 240D         24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2  4  --  3.19 -0.7318425
Merc 230          22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2  4  --  3.15 -0.7428921
Merc 280          19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4  6  --  3.44 -0.7784487
```

Next, I realized if I use

```
data$out <- rollapply(data.frame(data$mpg, data$wt), 8 ,function(x) cor(x[,1],x[,2]), by.column=FALSE, fill=NA, align='right')
```

this fixed the problem of having NA in the first 7 values, but still give a bunch of NA rows in the tail of the dataframe.
Any suggestion please? Thank you

Comment: `nrow(mtcars)`
`[1] 32`

mtcars only have 32 rows that's you had NA

Comment: yeah, but NAs should just be at the beginning of the dataframe, not at the end...

Comment: You tried to create more rows than what the mtcars dataset has so it created NA rows at the bottom. Run each line and view the data frame in R studio.

Comment: `data <- mtcars[1:50,]`  this line itself will create NA rows at the bottom

Comment: ah.....I see. I thought that dataframe had way more rows!!! Ok, so the align = right fixed the problem. Thank you !!!!